# Webpack - Include file multiple times

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, babel-loader, webpack-file-loader

I want to include a file twice through two different loaders. The reasoning is I want to display code snippets in ES6 while allowing them to be run in browsers not supporting the syntax.

Effectively what I would like to achieve is the below but with both loaders results being included in the output -

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel-loader"
},
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: /app\/examples/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          regExp: /app\/examples\/([^\/]+)\/([^\.]+)+\.jsx?$/,
          name: 'examples/[1]/[2].example',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

With the above in my webpack config

```
import example from '../../examples/simple/ex1'
```

results in

```
Module {default: "examples/simple/ex1.example", __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

Rather than the code run through babel as I would have hoped for.

Comment: You can use multiloader in webpack. For more info — https://github.com/webpack-contrib/multi-loader/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @MohitTilwani - I was looking at that. Could you explain how to map the config above through to it? - The examples seem to all use the older module.loaders syntax so i'm unsure how i'd pass through the options to file-loader.

Answer (score 1):

```
const multi = require('multi-loader');
const combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');

module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: /app\/examples/,
      loader: multi(combineLoaders([
        { loader: 'file-loader' },
        { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      ]))
    },
  ]
}
```

This should do the trick. you have to also use combineLoaders as you have to use options object. inside combine loaders array you can pass loader configuration also.

Comment: So I tried something similar to this. The problem is the file-loader'd file still ends up run through babel.

Comment: @Hector i just edited the answer by changing the order. Can you give it a try please. So now babel-loader will execute first and then file-loader

Comment: That still isn't working. I've ended up working around it using copy-webpack-plugin instead - which I actually think is cleaner.

Comment: `multi-loader` has been deprecated https://github.com/webpack-contrib/multi-loader Not sure what the alternative is

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to handle this with loaders in the end - although with further reading I don't believe this was the correct approach anyway. Instead i'm now using copy-webpack-plugin to copy the files -

```
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([ {
    from: path.join(rootDir, 'app', 'examples'),
    to: path.join(outputDir, 'examples')
  }])
],
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }
  ]
}
```