# Applying Different Loaders To Same File in Webpack

Tags: image-processing, webpack, webpack-4

I am looking to apply different loaders to the same set of files so that two different outputs are produced. Specifically, I want to perform the following so that some larger images are created and also some smaller ones:

```
...
{
    test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
    loader: 'my-loader',
    options: {/* specific for generating a certain size of image */}
},
{
    test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
    loader: 'my-loader',
    options: {/* specific for generating a different size of image */}
}
...
```

I was looking at "multi-loader" in combination with "webpack-combine-loaders" as detailed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260488/1424591 but the Githib repo at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/multi-loader is marked as deprecated and the WebPack site at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/multi-loader states "dependencies: out of date" but I haven't been able to source why this is the case. Should I be using soemthing else?